# How not to delete category if it has products?

Tags: laravel-4

I have a product which has a category name: "Shorts". So if I'll delete the category name shorts the product will also be deleted. So, I want, if the shorts will be deleted it will not delete because it has a product. Help me please

Function of my delete category...

```
   public function destroy(){
         $category= Category::find(Input::get('id'));

         if($category){
            $category->delete();
            return Redirect::to('admin/categories/index')
                ->with('message', 'Category Deleted');
         }

         return Redirect::to('admin/categories')
            ->with('message', 'Something went wrong');
```

Comment: Have you read about the concept of "cascade" in ORM systems? It seems like you don't want this relationship to cascade deletes. There are lots of ways to accomplish this, the question is - why are the items being deleted? That is not the default behavior of SQL, so where are the additional SQL DELETEs being generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check if there's a product belongs to that category

```
Product::where('category_id', Input::get('id'))->count();
```

Then simply delete the category if the count is not greater than 0. *Not tested *

```
$products = Product::where('category_id', Input::get('id'))->count();
    if($products > 0){
         return Redirect::to('admin/categories')
                ->with('message', 'Something went wrong');
    }
    else{
        $category= Category::find(Input::get('id'));
        $category->delete();
        return Redirect::to('admin/categories/index')
                    ->with('message', 'Category Deleted');
    }
```